# jQuery animate() different in Firefox and Chrome/IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, srware-iron

Currently I'm testing my webpage in different browsers for compatibility, however, I'm having an issue with my jQuery `animate()` in Chrome (using SRWare Iron) and IE.

I'm using the following code:

**jQuery**

```
$('.element').animate({top:"50px"}, 1400);
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="element">testing text slide</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
    .element {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1000px;
    left: 50px;
    font: bold 72px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The issue I'm having, is that in Firefox (Aurora), `element` slides from the bottom of the screen (-1000px) up to the top anchor of 50px.

In Chrome and IE, what seems to be happening is that `element` is sliding from 0px on the top, down to the 50px from the top, so it's very short. If I remove the jQuery animate for `element`, it's positioned at -1000px (I think, it's off the screen so I assume that's where it is).

Does anyone have any ideas? The other elements I'm animating with it work properly in FF/IE/Chrome.

Comment: I guess it's happening because the animation tries to animate from the current set value for top. And if it's not set, it could be set to "0" by the browser and this will have a higher priority than the value of bottom. What happens, if you use "top:1000px;" instead of "bottom:-1000px;". This is just a guess, as I'm writing from my phone and can't test it.

Comment: I changed the `bottom:-1000px` to `top:1900px` and it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be consistently manipulating only one of `top` or `bottom`.  Right now your CSS sets `bottom` and then your animation changes `top`.  As the two are obviously not independent, you will be much more likely to get consistency if you set and manipulate only one of them.  When you haven't set a value for `top`, then the javascript animation is probably getting an inconsistent starting value for `top` that the animation will start from.  It's probably coming back as `auto` in some browsers and some numeric value in other browsers.  You can bypass that whole inconsistency if you don't rely on a value that you haven't set.

Since your CSS sets `bottom`, I would suggest that you animate `bottom` also, not `top`.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. I used yours and insertusernameheres answer to fix it, changing `bottom: -1000px` to `top: 1900px` makes it nice and smooth.